# Converting Json string to C# object with C# 2.0 code

Tags: c#, json

I was using the following code in my dummy project to access a value from the json result.

```
var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
var links = item["links"];
var link = links[index];
return link["href"];
```

Now I have to implement it in the project and unfortunately it is in C# 2.0 ad hence doesn't support dynamic key word. Can any one suggest an alternate method that will fit in C# 2.0?

Comment: `Object`, maybe?  Not as many options available in 2.0.

Comment: @Tim I tried with object. But that makes `item["links"]` invalid

Comment: There is no such thing as a C# object....

Comment: How about `T item = serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);` where `T` is the type you expect to find there? It looks like you know the data type if you use indexers in next lines.

Comment: @S_F Ya, now i am wrking on it.I thought there would be some simpler way without creating the class.

Comment: It's not like the class isn't created anyway, it's just that you don't have to explicitly type it when using `dynamic`.

Comment: @leppie - Not sure what you mean.  `System.Object` has been part of C# since 1.0....

Comment: @Tim: How is a .NET type a C# object? The latter is some completely made-up term.